# Invalid plugin.yml file: What am i doing wrong?

Tags: yaml, bukkit

I am fairly confident with Bukkit/ Spigot coding, however I have run into a problem with my plugin.yml file...

Here is the plugin.yml:

```
name: PepsiAPI
version: 1.0
author: PepsiParadise
main: com.pepsiapi.Core
description: Core API for the PepsiParadise server

commands:
    papihelp:
        description: Displays the help page
    papiversion:
        description: Displays the plugin version
    tpto:
        description Teleports you to a player
    tphere:
        description: Teleports a player to you

permissions:
    pepsiapi.*:
        description: Contains all PepsiAPI permissions
        default: op
        children:
            pepsiapi.commands.*: true
    pepsiapi.commands.*:
        description: Contains all PepsiAPI command permissions
        default: op
        children:
            pepsiapi.command.help: true
            pepsiapi.command.tpto: true
            pepsiapi.command.tphere: true
            pepsiapi.command.version: true
    pepiapi.command.help:
        description: Displays the help page
        default: true
    pepsiapi.command.tpto:
        description: Teleports you to a player
        default: op
    pepsiapi.command.tphere:
        description: Teleports a player to you
        default: op
    pepsiapi.command.version:
        description: Displays the plugin version
        default: true
```

And here is the run.bat log file:

```
[17:35:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.8.7
[17:35:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[17:35:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: ADVENTURE
[17:35:20] [Server thread/INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f (MC: 1.8.7) (Implementing API version 1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[17:35:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Debug logging is disabled
[17:35:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
[17:35:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Server Ping Player Sample Count: 12
[17:35:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[17:35:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[17:35:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[17:35:23] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\PepsiAPI.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: commands are of wrong type
    at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.loadMap(PluginDescriptionFile.java:946) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.<init>(PluginDescriptionFile.java:232) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:159) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:133) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:291) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:198) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:524) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.loadMap(PluginDescriptionFile.java:928) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    ... 7 more
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Set PluginClassLoader as parallel capable
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: [PermissionsEx] Loading PermissionsEx v1.23.3
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Loading WorldEdit v6.1;no_git_id
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: **** Beginning UUID conversion, this may take A LONG time ****
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "hub"
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: -------- World Settings For [hub] --------
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: View Distance: 10
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Allow Zombie Pigmen to spawn from portal blocks: true
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Chunks to Grow per Tick: 650
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Clear tick list: false
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Experience Merge Radius: 3.0
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Merge Radius: 2.5
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Despawn Rate: 6000
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Cactus Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Cane Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Melon Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Mushroom Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Pumpkin Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Sapling Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Wheat Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: NetherWart Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Mob Spawn Range: 4
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Nerfing mobs spawned from spawners: false
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Anti X-Ray: true
[17:35:23] [Server thread/INFO]:    Engine Mode: 1
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]:    Hidden Blocks: [14, 15, 16, 21, 48, 49, 54, 56, 73, 74, 82, 129, 130]
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]:    Replace Blocks: [1, 5]
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Tile Max Tick Time: 50ms Entity max Tick Time: 50ms
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Activation Range: An 32 / Mo 32 / Mi 16
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Max TNT Explosions: 100
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Hopper Transfer: 8 Hopper Check: 8 Hopper Amount: 1
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Tracking Range: Pl 48 / An 48 / Mo 48 / Mi 32 / Other 64
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Random Lighting Updates: false
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Structure Info Saving: true
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Sending up to 10 chunks per packet
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Arrow Despawn Rate: 1200
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Zombie Aggressive Towards Villager: true
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Max Entity Collisions: 8
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Feature: 14357617
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: -------- World Settings For [hub_the_end] --------
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: View Distance: 10
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Allow Zombie Pigmen to spawn from portal blocks: true
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Chunks to Grow per Tick: 650
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Clear tick list: false
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Experience Merge Radius: 3.0
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Merge Radius: 2.5
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Despawn Rate: 6000
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Cactus Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Cane Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Melon Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Mushroom Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Pumpkin Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Sapling Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Wheat Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: NetherWart Growth Modifier: 100%
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Mob Spawn Range: 4
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Nerfing mobs spawned from spawners: false
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Anti X-Ray: true
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]:    Engine Mode: 1
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]:    Hidden Blocks: [14, 15, 16, 21, 48, 49, 54, 56, 73, 74, 82, 129, 130]
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]:    Replace Blocks: [1, 5]
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Tile Max Tick Time: 50ms Entity max Tick Time: 50ms
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Activation Range: An 32 / Mo 32 / Mi 16
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Max TNT Explosions: 100
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Hopper Transfer: 8 Hopper Check: 8 Hopper Amount: 1
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Tracking Range: Pl 48 / An 48 / Mo 48 / Mi 32 / Other 64
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Random Lighting Updates: false
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Structure Info Saving: true
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Sending up to 10 chunks per packet
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Arrow Despawn Rate: 1200
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Zombie Aggressive Towards Villager: true
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Max Entity Collisions: 8
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Feature: 14357617
[17:35:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: 7017054136831560976)
[17:35:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 35%
[17:35:26] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: 7017054136831560976)
[17:35:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 33%
[17:35:28] [Server thread/INFO]: [PermissionsEx] Enabling PermissionsEx v1.23.3
[17:35:28] [Server thread/INFO]: [PermissionsEx] Initializing file backend
[17:35:28] [Server thread/INFO]: [PermissionsEx] Permissions file successfully reloaded
[17:35:28] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Enabling WorldEdit v6.1;no_git_id
[17:35:30] [Server thread/INFO]: WEPIF: PermissionsEx detected! Using PermissionsEx for permissions.
[17:35:31] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Using com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.adapter.impl.Spigot_v1_8_R3 as the Bukkit adapter
[17:35:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[17:35:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (7.613s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

Here is what I think is causing the problem:
(I know it's in the file above, it's just I thought I might as well post the whole thing):

```
17:35:23] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\PepsiAPI.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: commands are of wrong type
    at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.loadMap(PluginDescriptionFile.java:946) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.<init>(PluginDescriptionFile.java:232) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:159) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:133) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:291) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:198) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:524) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.loadMap(PluginDescriptionFile.java:928) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f]
    ... 7 more
```

If you need me to post any more files then just tell me if it will help resolve the issue.

If it helps, the only other plugins running on the server are PermissionsEx, and Worldedit. The server is running spigot-1.8.1-RO1snapshot, and when you do /version it comes up with:

```
This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Spigot-ec3f46e-2359f6f (MC: 1.8.7) (Implementing API version 1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
description Teleports you to a player
```

Missing a colon.

Comment: Thank you! I'm so stupid! I can't believe I did that! Once again thank you